# Facing some issue in solving this equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, numerical-linear-algebra

I need to solve an equation where I need to find values of a, b, c and d such that the 3a + 3b + 3c + 2d = 100.

Possible equations

```
3a + 3b + 3c + 2d = 100
3a + 3b + 2c + 3d = 100
3a + 3b + 1c + 4d = 100 
3a + 5b + 1c + 2d = 100
```

I have many such set of equations which needs to have the same exact sum (that is 100).

Possible values could be for example - 11, 10.5, 10.. upto 7.

P.S I am not from maths background but I am sure that someone with knowledge in Maths can helps me solve this. Further more English is not my first language and most of my maths I have studied is in different language and we have our own names for different set of equations. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One equation with $4$ unknowns is not usually enough information to uniquely determine the values.  *Four* linear equations with $4$ unknowns might be.  You say you have many such equations, share those other equations.  In any event, solving for the values varies depending on the type of equations involved but if they are all *linear equations* then this is a very standard problem type solved by standard techniques from linear algebra.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations for an overview.

Comment: okay, - let me add more equations

Comment: For context also, it helps to confirm whether you are looking *only* for integer solutions, or if any real solutions are allowed.  The specific class of problems where you look specifically for integer solutions require different techniques in many cases and are labeled as [diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation).

Comment: Please tell us *all* you know.

Comment: okay - what i want is for different combination of a, b, c, d with above given equations and values mentioned (in range of 11.5, 11, 10, 10.5.... possible values of a,b,c and d) - the sum should be 100, I want to find the possible combinations for a,b,c,d  's values.

Comment: So, use standard techniques from linear algebra.  Set up the information as an augmented matrix $\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}3&3&3&2&100\\3&3&2&3&100\\3&3&1&4&100\\3&5&1&2&100\end{array}\right]$ and [row reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) to arrive at [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B3%2C3%2C3%2C2%2C100%7D%2C%7B3%2C3%2C2%2C3%2C100%7D%2C%7B3%2C3%2C1%2C4%2C100%7D%2C%7B3%2C5%2C1%2C2%2C100%7D%7D) to find there are infinitely many possibilities still.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you for the answer but how this will give me the variable values for a,b,c and d ?

Comment: Specifically, reading the results of the row reduction, we find that every outcome is of the form $a=\frac{100}{3}-\frac{8}{3}t,~b=t,c=t,d=t$.  Any choice of a value of $t$ will lead to a solution, for instance with $t=0$ that would be $a=\frac{100}{3},~b=c=d=0$.  Or with $t=3$ that would be $a=\frac{100}{3}-8,~b=c=d=3$ etc...  This should all be covered in the first chapter or two of any introductory linear algebra course and similar techniques can often be found in any highschool algebra course as well.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this? - I am asking for my knowledge. I understand your solution now.

Comment: @JMoravitz - Thank you..(y)

Comment: @stevengregory It is  -row1 + 2row2 = row3

Comment: The determinant of the matrix you described above is 0. That means that the four equations are linearly dependent. For example: -row1 + 2row2 = row3.